# Is it possible to allow a user to only edit categories of posts and nothing else?

Tags: permissions

I have a site with a lot of articles that aren't categorized. I'd like to hire someone to go through the articles and assign categories to them, then submit them for review and approval. However, if they can also edit the text of the articles the whole review/approval process by me would take up a lot of time as I'll have to check the text on a lot of articles.

So is there a way to set permissions in such a way that the specified user can only tweak the categories of a post and **NOTHING** else?

Any alternative ideas are also welcome.

Comment: I think I've come up with it just have to test: `add_role('categorizer', 'Categorizer', array(
    'read' => true, // True allows that capability
    'manage_categories' => true,
    'edit_posts' => false,
    'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
));`

Comment: If you manage to solve this, please post your solution in the "answer" box below. You can then "accept" your own solution.

Comment: After various tests it seems there is no way to achieve this.